# Background color not changing dropdown and navbar

Tags: css, colors, background, hover, navbar

This changes the color of the dropdown menu and navbar text but not changing  the background color of the dropdown menu and navbar

```css
        .dropdown-menu li > a
        {
            color: #7A7A7A;
        }
        .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
        dropdown-menu > li > a:focus 
        {
           color: #3399FF;
           text-decoration: none;
           background-color: #222 !important;
        }
       .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
       .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
       .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus 
       {
           color: #3377FF;
           background-color: #222 !important;
       }
```

Comment: are you missing a class identifier (.) in   dropdown-menu > li > a:focus line in the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in latest bootstrap they put background image on background when i run

```css
background-image:none;
```

this remove image and color show up.